# Formbuilder setvalue() is not working as expected when used on dropdown selects

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

Angular 2,4 formbuilder setvalue()  is not working as expected when used on dropdown selects.

I have the following dropdown select that gets populated with Github organizations:

```
  <select name="org" formControlName="organizations">
    <option *ngFor="let org of organizations" [ngValue]="org">{{org.organization.login}}</option>
  </select>
```

Here is the javascript code that sets the Github organization that should be selected.

```
  this.pipelineForm = fb.group({
      name:'',
      organizations:'',
      repos: '',
      branches:'',
      runtime:'',
      versions:''
    });

  userService.getOrganizations().subscribe((org:github)=>{
  let organizationName = org.data[0];
   this.organizations = org.data;
      this.projects.subscribe((p)=> {
        p[1].project.subscribe((f)=>{

         this.pipelineForm.get("organizations").setValue(f.organizations, {onlySelf: true});

          //this.pipelineForm.patchValue(f);
        });
      });

    });
```

I expect the corresponding dropdown option to be selected when I pass the value to the `setValue()`. Instead, I get a blank option. I also tried with `patchValue()`. No luck.
[image]

Comment: Use `compareWith` to provide a comparator function. https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Comment: I got a similar issue, and it's not only not working on dropdown but on any type of field. I need to update my form values based on a subscription and it just does not work with "setValue". I don't get it.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem and found Igor's answer. It was too vague so I dug around more. I finally figured it out, and Igor's answer is correct albeit lacking in detail. Hopefully this will help anyone else in the future trying to get `setValue()` on dropdowns and object models to work happily together.

Generally, the object model passed into `setValue()` should be the same as the objects you inject into your dropdown selector. E.g. if of type `Organization`, then the `setValue` should be also be of type `Organization`. It's not necessary, however, to share completely identical properties.

To get the `setValue()` or `patchValue()` to work with an object model (as opposed to some primitive type), use the `[compareWith]` function as Igor pointed out.

From `node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts`:

> compareWith is a function to compare the option values with the selected values.
>   The first argument is a value from an option. The second is a value
>   from the selection. A boolean should be returned.

In your html template,

```
<select [compareWith]="compareOrgs" name="org" formControlName="organizations">
    <option *ngFor="let org of organizations" [ngValue]="org">{{org.organization.login}}</option>
</select>
```

And in your  `component.ts` file, define the `compareOrgs()` function:

```
compareOrgs(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
   return c1 && c2 ? c1.orgId === c2.orgId : c1 === c2; 
}
```

Don't forget to call the `setValue()` function, for e.g. in `ngOnInit()` or in the callback function if it's async and you're fetching data.

E.g. in the callback from OP's code above,

```
// "organization" is whatever object you're trying to patch on the dropdown
this.pipelineForm.get("organizations").setValue(organization)
```

So what all this does is, the `compareOrgs` function will compare the value of the **selected** value (which is the object you passed *into* `setValue`, now labelled as `c2` in `compareOrgs`) with each of the **option** values (`c1`). Specifically, it compares the `orgId` properties of the selected and option values. This is how the `FormControl` knows which value to pre-select on the dropdown.

You can now access the object with `[ngValue]`.

This is a good resource that helped me: https://codeburst.io/angular-material-select-module-the-comparewith-function-9dfdb4035373

Answer (score 0):

A little example, we want to save a number. see [ngValue]="org.id" and this.myForm.controls['organization'].setValue(value);

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
interface Iorganization {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
    <select name="org" formControlName="organization">
      <option *ngFor="let org of organizations" [ngValue]="org.id">{{org.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <button (click)="setOrg(1)">Org 1</button>
  <button (click)="setOrg(2)">Org 2</button>
  {{myForm.value |json}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  organizations: Iorganization[];
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.organizations = [
      { id: 1, name: "org 1" },
      { id: 2, name: "org 2" },
      { id: 3, name: "org 3" },
      { id: 4, name: "org 4" }
    ];
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      organization: 1
    })
  }
  setOrg(value: number) {
    this.myForm.controls['organization'].setValue(value);
  }
}
```

if we want to save a object -see {{myForm.value |json}}- we need make a few changes. see that we put [ngValue]="org",  but the setOrg() function use a object to make setValue. And not, it's not valid setValue({id:1,name:'org1'})

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
....
template: `
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
    <select name="org" formControlName="organization">
      <option *ngFor="let org of organizations" [ngValue]="org">{{org.name}}</option>
    </select>
  ....`
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
ngOnInit() {
   this.organizations = [
     { id: 1, name: "org 1" },
        ....
    ];
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      organization: null
    })
}
setOrg(value: number) {
   let organization=this.organizations.find(o=>o.id==value);
   this.myForm.controls['organization'].setValue(organization);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the attribute `compareWith` on your `select` tag:

```
<select ... [compareWith]="compareByName">
```

Then implement a simple function in your component

```
compareByName(org1: Org, org2: Org): boolean {
  return org1 && org2 ? org1.name === org2.name : org1 === org2;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind your select's value is, as you have defined, is an object (Do you want to say < option *ngFor="let org of organizations" [ngValue]="***org.id**" >?

Comment: @Eliseo not sure what you are saying -- the OP's post does not mention the `id` property anywhere in the `org` model.

Comment: It's only an e.g. what's "org"? is an object, So, you must using a object in the setValue. Other options is that the value is a string or a number, but then you must put as value ord.organitation.id, e.g.

Comment: I wrote a little example