# Using Angular8 compareWith and form setValue to set selected item in a dropdown menu, couldn't work in chrome 83

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am trying to set a selected item in a dropdown list using angular compareWith. However, it doesn't work well. The dropdown menu is still a blank. Here is my code: I created a demo at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzajdk) I found it shows well on FireFox and Safari, but not for Chrome 83

```
<select class="custom-select w-100 form-control 
    (change)="changeTitle(time2TrackForm.value.title)" 
    formControlName="title"  
    [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <option [ngValue]="''">
        <b>Select</b>
    </option>
    <option *ngFor="let title of subsectionTitles" 
        [ngValue]="title" id="selectedItem">
        <b>{{title}}</b>
    </option>
</select>
```

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit () {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group(this._formModel());
    this._getIntegrations(); // make a call to fetch the data
}

private _formmModel() {
    return {
        title: ['', [Validators.required]],
        actions: this.fb.array([],[Validators.required]),
        source: ['', [Validators.required]],
    };
}

private _getIntegrations(): void {
    this.service
        .getData(id).pipe(
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.list = data;
            //  can successfully get the data here for sure
            (this.mode === 'Edit') && this._setCollection();
    });
}

private _setCollection(): void {
    this.time2TrackForm.get('title').setValue('Test Title'); 
    this.subsectionTitles = this.list.titles;
    console.log(this.subsectionTitles) // ['Test Title']
    this.spinnerForData = false;
}

compareFn(val1: string, val2: string) {
    console.log(val1 === val2) // eventally return true
    return (val1 && val2) && val1 === val2;
};
```

I am using **Chrome 83**. And refers to this [Formbuilder setvalue() is not working as expected when used on dropdown selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780829/formbuilder-setvalue-is-not-working-as-expected-when-used-on-dropdown-selects) way, but still couldn't get any luck. No idea why in this such way, the dropdown list is still blank, but I found the item has been selected. Does anyone experience this? Many thanks

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: If your select options are strings or number you needn't use compareWith -it's only if the [ngValue] of th options are "objects". Take account that your `this.subsectionTitles` has no values if the function _setCollection not executed, e.g. is `this.mode!=='Edit'`. do you has any error in console?

Comment: Hi @Chellappanவ I created one at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzajdk  I noticed that Firefox and Safari show well but Chrome 34 doesn't work well

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, thank you so much. I created a similar one on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzajdk it works well on firefox and safari, but not chrome 34, could you please take look at it and let me know what I have done is wrong. Appreciated a lot

Comment: Really it's strange the Chrome 34 problem. I answer a work-around but I can not find the reason

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, sorry, my bad, should be Chrome 83 (currently latest version) not chrome 34. I have modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it's strange the Chrome 83 problem. You can solve if you enclosed the setValue in a setTimeout, but, for me have no logic, if I found the reason I tell you :(

```
this.subsectionTitles = this.list.titles;
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.time2TrackForm.get("title").setValue(this.inputTitle);
})
```

Comment: this is awesome! Look like it works well. I found out if this.list.titles has two elements, it will show the top one. For example: this.list.titles = ['Test1', 'Test2'], if selected item is 'Test1', it will show 'Test1', but not for 'Test2'. So, I almost manipulate the dom like ['Test1', '' ], which makes the last item hidden on the page, but definitely your solution is way much better. If you can, could you let me know, why you thought about settimeout() can solve the issue? Anyway, many many thanks! This really helped me a lot!!

Comment: a "setTimeout()" give angular a breath (it's som elike you say to Angular: 'hey make all the actions, and, after repaint the application, remember that you need make this one more instrucction), so first fill the select and after give the value. As when we give the value, the "opstions" are filled, the select show the option. But I don't know what is the reason Mozilla work

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, this makes scenes! Thanks a lot!